# Wygwam Module: Browse server button hidden

Tags: members, file-uploads, wygwam

For member groups other than Super Admin, the "browse server" button is hidden when trying to import an image into the content area while editing.

I've tried turning on all member group options...changing the File Browser for Wigwam between CKFinder and EE Manager, no luck.

Running EE 2.4.0 - would the upgrade fix it?

Any other solutions or things to try welcome. Would rather not make everyone a Super Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you need to adjust is on the [**File Upload Preferences**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#restrict-file-uploading-to-select-member-groups) page. Look for "Restrict file uploading to select member groups" at the bottom.

**CP LOCATION**
Content ‣ Files ‣ File Upload Preferences

Comment: Thanks! Turns out upload folder wasn't what I expected, so hadn't updated the right Preference.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it sorted.